# Problems With `app_crypto!` Macro

Tags: cryptography, key, macro, coreprimitives

I have the following error while building:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `generate_with_phrase` found for struct `crain_pow::app::Pair` in the current scope
   --> node/src/service.rs:211:49
    |
211 |         let (pair, phrase, _) = crain_pow::app::Pair::generate_with_phrase(None);
    |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `crain_pow::app::Pair`
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
```

A `Pair` type is declared using `app_crypto!` macro in another file:

```
pub mod app {
    use sp_application_crypto::{app_crypto, sr25519};
    use sp_core::crypto::KeyTypeId;

    pub const ID: KeyTypeId = KeyTypeId(*b"crn1");
    app_crypto!(sr25519, ID);
}
```

Which enables another macro which implements the `generate_with_phrase` function (*code from substrate's github repo*):

```
/// Implements functions for the `Pair` trait when `feature = "std"` is enabled.
#[doc(hidden)]
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! app_crypto_pair_functions_if_std {
    ($pair:ty) => {
        fn generate_with_phrase(password: Option<&str>) -> (Self, String, Self::Seed) {
            let r = <$pair>::generate_with_phrase(password);
            (Self(r.0), r.1, r.2)
        }

        fn from_phrase(
            phrase: &str,
            password: Option<&str>,
        ) -> Result<(Self, Self::Seed), $crate::SecretStringError> {
            <$pair>::from_phrase(phrase, password).map(|r| (Self(r.0), r.1))
        }
    };
}
```

I see that is requires `sp-application-crypto`'s `std` feature to be enabled (#[cfg(feature = "std")]). So I enable it in my package's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
sp-application-crypto = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
***snip***
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "sp-application-crypto/std", # enables sp-application-crypto/full_crypto as well
]
```

So the `std` (and `full_crypto` as well) feature requirement is satisfied. But I still get the error saying that `generate_with_phrase` function is not implemented.

What might be the problem?

(P.S. [This](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/5558/commits/ad83ed52f862357383f2d62f0202ed1277632fdb) is a MR adding that function long time ago into primitives)

Comment: Where are you trying to declare this app crypto type? You have made `default-features=false` which implies this may be inside the runtime, in which case, the runtime must compile without `std`, so you cannot declare such a macro in your runtime.

Comment: `app_crypto!` macro is used in `pow/src/lib.rs/` like [here](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/blob/0f89b1306803e4c7822f332dcdfeaeca7ccc6c6c/pow/src/lib.rs#L47).  

`Cargo.toml` lines I've provided are from `pow/Cargo.toml`.    

`pow` crate is in the same directory as `node`, `pallets`, `runtime`, etc.

Comment: I've tried removing `default-features = false`, tried adding `features = ["full_crypto"]` in that  .toml, tried deleting whole `[features]` section of that .toml - nothing helped

Comment: `pow` crate is imported to the `node` crate

Comment: You should just add the dependency like: `sp-application-crypto = { version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }`. With no features or anything. This should work, otherwise, you will need to share more details about your project, and the changes you made.

Comment: Ok, I have another question then. This [line](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/primitives/application-crypto/src/lib.rs#L189) here says "`std` feature is enabled". Is that `sp-application-crypto`'s `std` feature or any other pallet's? Should I only activate `std` feature of that pallet or of __all__ pallets that import this pallet?

Comment: I mentioned above, you CANNOT do `std` in the runtime or in Pallets. This code cannot exist inside a pallet, it will never compile. This code must live in the client of your node, which is all `std`. So you will not be able to get app_crypto macro working in the runtime/pallet code.

Comment: `app_crypto!` -> `pow` crate -> `node` crate. So this macro does live in the client of the node where `std` is allowed. It has nothing to do with runtime. Sorry, I meant 'crates', not 'pallets' in the previous comment.

Comment: As you can see in the [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/blob/0f89b1306803e4c7822f332dcdfeaeca7ccc6c6c/pow/Cargo.toml) for `pow` there are no mentions of features being enabled. You can see in [`application-crypto`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/application-crypto/Cargo.toml), the default feature is `[std]`, so if you put no features, std is default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found the solution.

Rust has quite a weird behavior of traits. Let's say we have:
`libA` with `traitA` (which hash `show()` function),
`libB` with `struct structB` and `impl traitA for structB`
`libC` with code: `structB::show()`

The last line won't compile. Because, as it turns out, you have to first import `traitA` **into** `libC` with `use libA::traitA`.

In my case:
`libA` was `sp_core`,
`libB` was `pow` crate,
`libC` was `node` crate,

The solution:
(in the beginning of `node/src/service.rs`)
**`use sp_core::Pair;`**
That's it! It had nothing to do with `Cargo.toml`'s at all!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be with how you are importing this crate.

Rust's feature system is quite strange in behavior, and if there is any situation where you try to use the `app_crypto!` macro outside of `std`, you will hit this kind of error.

I suggest that you simply import this crate like so:

```toml
[dependencies]
sp-application-crypto = { version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
```

Which involves no features at all, and due to the [configuration of the `sp-application-crypto`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/application-crypto/Cargo.toml), this will imply `std` by default.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested and imported `sp-application-crypto` like that. It did not fix the bug. To me it seems completely obvious that `std` of that crate should be enabled in that case, and thus `full-crypto` should be enabled making [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a28c62246406839b746af2201309d0ed9a3f526/primitives/application-crypto/src/lib.rs#L63) and [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a28c62246406839b746af2201309d0ed9a3f526/primitives/application-crypto/src/lib.rs#L191) macros work. But it doesn't. I'm literally out of ideas now.

Comment: I also checked that none of [these](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a28c62246406839b746af2201309d0ed9a3f526/primitives/application-crypto/src/lib.rs#L136) function are callable. Which means that `app_crypto_pair` macro was not called which means that [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a28c62246406839b746af2201309d0ed9a3f526/primitives/application-crypto/src/lib.rs#L95) version of `app_crypto` was called which means that `full_crypto` was not enabled

Comment: You can check my [code](https://github.com/CREESTL/Crain/blob/main/pow/Cargo.toml) out

Comment: Even explicitly enabling both `std` and `full_crypto` features doesn't help: `sp-application-crypto = { version = "6.0.0", features = ["std", "full_crypto"], git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
`