# app_crypto!(sr25519, KEY_TYPE): cannot find trait `TryFrom` in this scope

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, no-std

I am building an ocw demo, the code is from https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs, when using polkadot-v0.9.25 version, it appears got this error:
**cannot find trait `TryFrom` in this scope**, I'm sure this code work with polkadot-v0.9.18.
[image]

Have read this question: [Problems With `app_crypto!` Macro](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/problems-with-app-crypto-macro), but it didn't solve my problem, this question is so confusing why not found and where this error is triggered

```
pub mod crypto {
    use super::KEY_TYPE;
    use sp_core::sr25519::Signature as Sr25519Signature;
    use sp_runtime::{
        app_crypto::{app_crypto, sr25519},
        traits::Verify,
        MultiSignature, MultiSigner,
    };
    app_crypto!(sr25519, KEY_TYPE);

    pub struct TestAuthId;

    impl frame_system::offchain::AppCrypto<MultiSigner, MultiSignature> for TestAuthId {
        type RuntimeAppPublic = Public;
        type GenericSignature = sp_core::sr25519::Signature;
        type GenericPublic = sp_core::sr25519::Public;
    }

    // implemented for mock runtime in test
    impl frame_system::offchain::AppCrypto<<Sr25519Signature as Verify>::Signer, Sr25519Signature>
        for TestAuthId
    {
        type RuntimeAppPublic = Public;
        type GenericSignature = sp_core::sr25519::Signature;
        type GenericPublic = sp_core::sr25519::Public;
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
lite-json = { version = "0.1", default-features = false }
log = { version = "0.4.17", default-features = false }
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }


# Substrate packages
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25", optional = true }
frame-support      = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
frame-system       = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
sp-std             = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
sp-keystore             = { version = "0.12.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25", optional = true}
sp-core = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
sp-io = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }


[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "lite-json/std",
    "log/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-io/std",
    "sp-keystore",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "sp-std/std",
]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

have tried `cargo clean`, `cargo update`,

```
rustup update
rustup update nightly
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

Comment: What is the command you are running to run into this error?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi `cargo build --release`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicetly importing `sp_core::Pair` as I've mentioned in the [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2787/2408) you linked above?

Comment: yes. I tried `sp_core::Pair`, but not work. fix it by add `use sp_std::{convert::TryFrom};` to `pub mod crypto`